# Can i split a List by element property into smaller lists

Tags: c#, list, group-by, split

I have a huge list of Answers to a survey and they all come together no matter the person, I have grouped the list by the ID of the person who answered but now I needed to split this list into smaller lists with with only the answers from a single person.

My big list now is called "surveyAnswers.Respostas", each individual answer is a "SurveyAnswer" and the property of the person id is "quemRespondeu"

Iam grouping the list like this:  "surveyAnswers.Respostas.GroupBy(x => x.quemRespondeu)"

How can i create a List with all the answers from a single person id??

Thx in advance guys!!

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the question, but seems the following should do the trick: `surveyAnswers.Respostas.Where(x => x.PersonId == yourSinglePersonId)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get a dictionary where keys are person ids and the values are Lists of all answers of the corresponding person:

```
var grouped = . . .GroupedBy(x => x.quemRespondeu);            //the result you have already

var listByRespondeu = grouped.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());    //answers by person id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to do the grouping first, but I cannot assure that the performance against Linq will be better. Actually the Linq code is simpler, which normally is much desired. Anyway, for the sake of completion, assuming quemRespondeu is of type long:

```cs
public  Dictionary<long,List<string>> GroupAnswers(List<Answer> AllAnswers)
        {
            long[] allIds = new long[AllAnswers.Count];
            Answer[] AllAnswersArray = AllAnswers.ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < AllAnswers.Count; i++)
                allIds[i] = AllAnswers[i].quemRespondeu;

            Array.Sort(allIds, AllAnswersArray);

            Dictionary<long, List<string>> DictAllAnswersGrouped = new Dictionary<long, List<string>>();
            List<string> ListCurrentUser = null;

            long prevId = allIds[0] - 1;//to assure that ListCurrentUser is initialized in the first iteration 
            for (int i=0; i< allIds.Length; i++)
            {
                long Id = allIds[i];
                if(Id!=prevId)
                {
                    ListCurrentUser = new List<string>();
                    DictAllAnswersGrouped.Add(Id, ListCurrentUser);
                    prevId = Id;
                }

                ListCurrentUser.Add(AllAnswersArray[i].SurveyAnswer);
            }

            return DictAllAnswersGrouped;
        }
```

Then you will call:

```cs
  Dictionary<long,List<string>> GroupedAnswersDict = GroupAnswers(surveyAnswers.Respostas);
  
  long user_XId = 10; //whatever you need
  List<string> userX_Answers;
   if (!GroupedAnswersDict.TryGetValue(userX_Id, out userX_Answers))
         userX_Answers = null;
```

**Disclaimer:**  As I said, Linq code is way simpler and readable so it should be the first choice in most of the cases. Nontheless, this code above can be choosen in some particular cases, for example, if some more complex functionality is needed, if Linq cannot be used or if it has any real benefit in performance.

Actually, out of curiosity, I did a little test to see how it performs and without further optimizations, Linq generally outperforms this algorithm (about 2x), even comparing it with the full equivalent:

```cs
   var grouped = surveyAnswers.Respostas.GroupBy(x => x.quemRespondeu);       
   Dictionary<long, List<string>> GroupedAnswersDict =
              grouped.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(l => l.SurveyAnswer).ToList());
```

Only in cases where the number of answers per user are very small compared to the number of users, this algorithm outperforms the Linq code above (less than 1.2x) but still slower than just class grouping (posted here by [Supa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/67002410/5714954), credits to him):

```cs
   var grouped = surveyAnswers.Respostas.GroupBy(x => x.quemRespondeu);       
   Dictionary<long, List<Answer>> GroupedAnswersDict = 
                     grouped.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

So in this case, performance is not a reason to chose it over Linq either.

Comment: This is basically the same as the previous answer but in dozens lines of code instead of one :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67002410/5714954

Comment: Absolutely, I posted the code for completion and also because I had my doubts about performance. But I just ran some tests and Linq clearly outperforms this code so I have updated my answer to set it clear